# Insert or update object in Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, vue.js

I am trying to insert or update already existed object in an empty Array in Vue.js:

```
additionalFields: [
                    {
                        name: '',
                        description: ''
                    }
                ]
```

I am getting the data from a child component:

```
updateAdditionalTitleForm(value, index) {
            this.$emit('updateAdditionalTitle', value, index);
        },
        updateAdditionalDescriptionForm(value, index) {
            this.$emit('updateAdditionalDescription', value, index);
        }
```

I am receiving the data correctly, I just don't seem to insert or update them correctly at the given index:

```
adaptAdditionalTitleForm(value, index) {
            this.form.additionalFields.push({ title: value });
        },
        adaptAdditionalDescriptionForm(value, index) {
            this.form.additionalFields.push({ description: value });
        }
```

This will create a separate object and I want to have title and description in one object. What to do?

Comment: When do you want to add/update entries to the array? And how do you treat the set of values to go to the same object? What are your business conditions?

Comment: On change input. It is like the end result of several inputs. So this component would be the review component of other components. I have no idea how to set the values. What do you mean by business condition?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the given `index` param to update particular object fields in the `additionalFields` array.

```
adaptAdditionalTitleForm(obj) {
   if(!obj.index || (obj.index && obj.index>=this.form.additionalFields.length)){
       this.form.additionalFields.push({title:object.value,description:''}) 
   }else if(obj.index) {
   this.form.additionalFields[obj.index].title= obj.value;
  }
},

adaptAdditionalDescriptionForm(obj) {
 if(!obj.index || (obj.index && obj.index>=this.form.additionalFields.length)){
   this.form.additionalFields.push({description:obj.value,title:''})
  }else if(obj.index){
     this.form.additionalFields[obj.index].description=obj.value;
  }
}
```

Also passing multiple arguments to emit doesn't work so you need to wrap them in an object.

```
updateAdditionalTitleForm(value, index) {
    this.$emit('updateAdditionalTitle', {value,index});
},
updateAdditionalDescriptionForm(value, index) {
   this.$emit('updateAdditionalDescription',{value,index});
}
```

Comment: This seems to work somehow but not 100%.
The problem is when I try to insert a new field into the array and emit it to the parent. I don't have the new object in the array of the parent. I can create new objects on the child component and fill them with data. So I want to create as much as I want and insert them or update them on the parent.

Comment: you need to pass flag 'isNew' true/false while emiting to either insert or update new value.

Comment: Or just don't pass the index when inserting new array this way if index is undefined you will push a new object

Comment: If you can explain what you did, I may help.

Comment: ```updateAdditionalDescriptionForm(value, index) {
                this.$emit('updateAdditionalDescription', { value, index });
            }``` and then I did this on the parent ```adaptAdditionalTitleForm(obj) {
                if (this.form.additionalFields.indexOf(obj.index) != null) {
                    this.form.additionalFields[obj.index].title = obj.value;
                } else {
                    this.form.additionalFields.push({ title: obj.value });
                }
            }```

Comment: In child, how do you know you are sending index value as undefined or not?

Comment: I am certainly not sending undefined. I console-log it and it works perfectly.

Comment: indexOf is used to get index of particular object.

Comment: I have updated the answer on the basis that if index value is greater than array length then insert into array else update. I am not sure how are you identifying when to update and when to insert?